# Name of variable passed as argument to function

Tags: python, function, dictionary, scope, arguments

I call a function with argument being list stored in dictionary under a specific key, and would like to use this key inside function.

```
def f(arg1):
    magic = 'a' # some magic that extracts the key 'a'
    return [(i, magic) for i in arg1 if i % 2 == 0]  

mydic = {'a':[1,2,3],'even':[]}
mydic['even'] = f(mydic['a'])  # [(2, 'a')]
```

---

One can work around with smth like

```
def f(arg1, nonmagic):
    return [(i, nonmagic) for i in arg1 if i % 2 == 0]  

mydic = {'a':[1,2,3],'even':[]}
mydic['even'] = f(mydic['a'], 'a')  # [(2, 'a')]
```

but that is not as nice.

Comment: Your `nonmagic` code is the only way. (Or `key = 'a'; f(mydic[key],key)`)

Comment: @quamrana how can you know it is the only way? I am trying to avoid passing key to function as it is defined already with first argument. Second argument is a repetition.

Comment: Unless you are examining the source code itself, `f` has no way of knowing that the value `[1,2,3]` bound to `arg1` comes from a `dict` at all, let alone which key in that dict is associated with it.

Comment: Logic tells me. There is no way that a function can know how its clients arrive at the values they use for `arg1`.

Comment: The key is *not* defined in the argument; it's part of the value from which the argument is produced.

Comment: If you are worried about an apparent redundancy, pass the entire `dict` and the key *separately*, and let `f` perform the indexing operation: `def f(arg_dict, arg_key): arg1 = arg_dict[arg_key]; ...`.

Comment: Put another way: what would you expect `magic` to be if I called `f` like `f(3)`? If your argument is that `f` should only be called using a `dict`, then that's what my suggestion in my previous comment conveys.

Comment: @chepner I would expect the magic to return '3' for f(3), 'a=3' for f(a=3), 'a={'b':3}' for a={'b':3} and f(a) etc.

Comment: "The key is not defined in the argument; it's part of the value from which the argument is produced." -- you pass data structure by key reference. Is this reference lost?

Comment: None of those expectations are realistic. The expressions are evaluated *before* the function is called, and they simply are not exposed to the function itself.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). The idea of names of variables in python it essentially the same as keys in a `dict`.

Comment: `mydic['a']` is not a reference to a `dict`; it's an expression that evaluates to the *value* stored with key `'a'`. That value has no idea if one of the (possibly many) references to it is stored in a `dict`.

Comment: Put another way, the name-to-value relationship is a one-way, many-to-one relation. There is no one-to-many relation of value-to-name stored anywhere.

Comment: @chepner your suggestion `def f(arg_dict, arg_key): arg1 = arg_dict[arg_key];` reduces the redundancy. Thanks.